# Inner class modifying owning class's attribute

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I have a code like this:

```
class Foo() {
    time_to_play = 0
    class Bar() {
        void change_player() {
            //I need something HERE
        }
    }

}
```

And I need to change the attribute `time_to_play` from class `Foo`, but make this change from inside the method `change_player()`, that is under class `Bar`.

I cannot declare class `Bar` outside class `Foo`, and make an 'extend', and call super. ..., because it'd break the OO in my case.

Also, I don't want to make `time_to_play` a static variable, calling `Foo.time_to_play`

How I can do this?

Comment: Also, ignore the lexical errors on the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is:

```
void change_player() {
    Foo.this.time_to_play = // something
}
```

Comment: Of course this is only needed in the case where the inner class has a field of the same name. Then again it's always good to be sure.